# compare multiple columns in a data frame with vector and add new column to the data frame indicating the matched cloumn name in R

Tags: r

```
my_vector <- c("g1","g2","g3","g4")

Read_1 Read_2 Read_3 Read_4
g1     o      o      g1
 o     g2     o      g2
g3     g3    g3      o
```

Read_1,2,3,4 are my data frames column name and i have a vector called my_vector. What i want is that take the vector and compare across the data frame and if match found report the matched column name. I tried with two columns but i don't know how compare with multiple columns

> This is my expected output

```
Read_1 Read_2 Read_3 Read_4 Match_cloumn
g1     o     o       g1      Read_1,Read_4
o      g2    o       g2      Read_2,Read_4
g3     g3    g3      o       Read_1,Read_2,Read_2
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I came here for `bash` and/or  `awk` - please don't use unrelated tags

Comment: I really appreciate if you do provide some information. Because the initial idea is awk with grep function. If you give something i really appreciate and love to try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could loop over the rows, (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`), subset the names of the based on the 'my_vector' elements and `paste`

```
df1$Match_column <- apply(df1, 1, function(x)
       toString(names(x)[x %in% my_vector]))
```

-output

```
 df1
  Read_1 Read_2 Read_3 Read_4           Match_column
1     g1      o      o     g1         Read_1, Read_4
2      o     g2      o     g2         Read_2, Read_4
3     g3     g3     g3      o Read_1, Read_2, Read_3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Read_1 = c("g1", "o", "g3"), Read_2 = c("o", "g2", 
"g3"), Read_3 = c("o", "o", "g3"), Read_4 = c("g1", "g2", "o"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```